# Filter Data Attributes jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to filter my List Items dependant on what data attributes they have. Please see my code below:

**HTML**

```
<li data-process="test 1 ; test 2 ; test 3;">Item</li>
<li data-process="test 2 ; test 3;">Item</li>
<li data-process="test 1 ; test 2 ; test 3;">Item</li>
<li data-process="test 2 ; test 3;">Item</li>
<li data-process="test 1 ; test 2 ; test 3;">Item</li>
```

**JS**

```
$('[data-process="test1"]').hide();
```

So then I would like all items with test 1 to hide.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the contains selector :

```
$('li[data-process*="test 1"]').hide();
```

See this fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zfdLvndy/1/

But keep in mind that this can be costful to retrieve elements like that...

Comment: This is the answer I think OP is looking for, but I'd suggest OP stores an array in those data attributes to make it easier to work with if you need to manipulate it a lot.

Comment: @BillCriswell : I agree with you :-)

Comment: This is good, but he should be aware that this would match something like `test12`. If the semicolons were more consistent as terminators, that would be useful, but the last one in the list lacks a space. :(

Comment: Thank you very much @SamuelCaillerie That has worked perfectly! And sixfingeredman apologies they are consistent in my code - c&p error. Many thanks again!

Comment: Here is a demo using an array. This way you could filter more than one without insane string concatenation: http://jsbin.com/wunifewunu/3/edit?html,js,output